# Typeahead get multiple value beside the list name

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I found its hard to imagine a way to obtain a set of value for the typeahead directive.

for example, in this plunker,http://plnkr.co/edit/Sj0kOGipJ4gNv3VCnKzJ?p=preview

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
  <a>
      <img ng-src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/{{match.model.flag}}" width="16">
      <span bind-html-unsafe="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
  </a>
</script>
<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">

    <h4>Static arrays</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">

    <h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control">
    <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>

    <h4>Custom templates for results</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{customSelected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" placeholder="Custom template" typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" class="form-control">
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

example.js

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope, $http) {

  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
  // Any function returning a promise object can be used to load values asynchronously
  $scope.getLocation = function(val) {
    return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
      params: {
        address: val,
        sensor: false
      }
    }).then(function(res){
      var addresses = [];
      angular.forEach(res.data.results, function(item){
        addresses.push(item.formatted_address);
      });
      return addresses;
    });
  };

  $scope.statesWithFlags = [{'name':'Alabama','flag':'5/5c/Flag_of_Alabama.svg/45px-Flag_of_Alabama.svg.png'},{'name':'Alaska','flag':'e/e6/Flag_of_Alaska.svg/43px-Flag_of_Alaska.svg.png'},{'name':'Arizona','flag':'9/9d/Flag_of_Arizona.svg/45px-Flag_of_Arizona.svg.png'},{'name':'Arkansas','flag':'9/9d/Flag_of_Arkansas.svg/45px-Flag_of_Arkansas.svg.png'},{'name':'California','flag':'0/01/Flag_of_California.svg/45px-Flag_of_California.svg.png'},{'name':'Colorado','flag':'4/46/Flag_of_Colorado.svg/45px-Flag_of_Colorado.svg.png'},{'name':'Connecticut','flag':'9/96/Flag_of_Connecticut.svg/39px-Flag_of_Connecticut.svg.png'},{'name':'Delaware','flag':'c/c6/Flag_of_Delaware.svg/45px-Flag_of_Delaware.svg.png'},{'name':'Florida','flag':'f/f7/Flag_of_Florida.svg/45px-Flag_of_Florida.svg.png'},{'name':'Georgia','flag':'5/54/Flag_of_Georgia_%28U.S._state%29.svg/46px-Flag_of_Georgia_%28U.S._state%29.svg.png'},{'name':'Hawaii','flag':'e/ef/Flag_of_Hawaii.svg/46px-Flag_of_Hawaii.svg.png'},{'name':'Idaho','flag':'a/a4/Flag_of_Idaho.svg/38px-Flag_of_Idaho.svg.png'},{'name':'Illinois','flag':'0/01/Flag_of_Illinois.svg/46px-Flag_of_Illinois.svg.png'},{'name':'Indiana','flag':'a/ac/Flag_of_Indiana.svg/45px-Flag_of_Indiana.svg.png'},{'name':'Iowa','flag':'a/aa/Flag_of_Iowa.svg/44px-Flag_of_Iowa.svg.png'},{'name':'Kansas','flag':'d/da/Flag_of_Kansas.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kansas.svg.png'},{'name':'Kentucky','flag':'8/8d/Flag_of_Kentucky.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kentucky.svg.png'},{'name':'Louisiana','flag':'e/e0/Flag_of_Louisiana.svg/46px-Flag_of_Louisiana.svg.png'},{'name':'Maine','flag':'3/35/Flag_of_Maine.svg/45px-Flag_of_Maine.svg.png'},{'name':'Maryland','flag':'a/a0/Flag_of_Maryland.svg/45px-Flag_of_Maryland.svg.png'},{'name':'Massachusetts','flag':'f/f2/Flag_of_Massachusetts.svg/46px-Flag_of_Massachusetts.svg.png'},{'name':'Michigan','flag':'b/b5/Flag_of_Michigan.svg/45px-Flag_of_Michigan.svg.png'},{'name':'Minnesota','flag':'b/b9/Flag_of_Minnesota.svg/46px-Flag_of_Minnesota.svg.png'},{'name':'Mississippi','flag':'4/42/Flag_of_Mississippi.svg/45px-Flag_of_Mississippi.svg.png'},{'name':'Missouri','flag':'5/5a/Flag_of_Missouri.svg/46px-Flag_of_Missouri.svg.png'},{'name':'Montana','flag':'c/cb/Flag_of_Montana.svg/45px-Flag_of_Montana.svg.png'},{'name':'Nebraska','flag':'4/4d/Flag_of_Nebraska.svg/46px-Flag_of_Nebraska.svg.png'},{'name':'Nevada','flag':'f/f1/Flag_of_Nevada.svg/45px-Flag_of_Nevada.svg.png'},{'name':'New Hampshire','flag':'2/28/Flag_of_New_Hampshire.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Hampshire.svg.png'},{'name':'New Jersey','flag':'9/92/Flag_of_New_Jersey.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Jersey.svg.png'},{'name':'New Mexico','flag':'c/c3/Flag_of_New_Mexico.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Mexico.svg.png'},{'name':'New York','flag':'1/1a/Flag_of_New_York.svg/46px-Flag_of_New_York.svg.png'},{'name':'North Carolina','flag':'b/bb/Flag_of_North_Carolina.svg/45px-Flag_of_North_Carolina.svg.png'},{'name':'North Dakota','flag':'e/ee/Flag_of_North_Dakota.svg/38px-Flag_of_North_Dakota.svg.png'},{'name':'Ohio','flag':'4/4c/Flag_of_Ohio.svg/46px-Flag_of_Ohio.svg.png'},{'name':'Oklahoma','flag':'6/6e/Flag_of_Oklahoma.svg/45px-Flag_of_Oklahoma.svg.png'},{'name':'Oregon','flag':'b/b9/Flag_of_Oregon.svg/46px-Flag_of_Oregon.svg.png'},{'name':'Pennsylvania','flag':'f/f7/Flag_of_Pennsylvania.svg/45px-Flag_of_Pennsylvania.svg.png'},{'name':'Rhode Island','flag':'f/f3/Flag_of_Rhode_Island.svg/32px-Flag_of_Rhode_Island.svg.png'},{'name':'South Carolina','flag':'6/69/Flag_of_South_Carolina.svg/45px-Flag_of_South_Carolina.svg.png'},{'name':'South Dakota','flag':'1/1a/Flag_of_South_Dakota.svg/46px-Flag_of_South_Dakota.svg.png'},{'name':'Tennessee','flag':'9/9e/Flag_of_Tennessee.svg/46px-Flag_of_Tennessee.svg.png'},{'name':'Texas','flag':'f/f7/Flag_of_Texas.svg/45px-Flag_of_Texas.svg.png'},{'name':'Utah','flag':'f/f6/Flag_of_Utah.svg/45px-Flag_of_Utah.svg.png'},{'name':'Vermont','flag':'4/49/Flag_of_Vermont.svg/46px-Flag_of_Vermont.svg.png'},{'name':'Virginia','flag':'4/47/Flag_of_Virginia.svg/44px-Flag_of_Virginia.svg.png'},{'name':'Washington','flag':'5/54/Flag_of_Washington.svg/46px-Flag_of_Washington.svg.png'},{'name':'West Virginia','flag':'2/22/Flag_of_West_Virginia.svg/46px-Flag_of_West_Virginia.svg.png'},{'name':'Wisconsin','flag':'2/22/Flag_of_Wisconsin.svg/45px-Flag_of_Wisconsin.svg.png'},{'name':'Wyoming','flag':'b/bc/Flag_of_Wyoming.svg/43px-Flag_of_Wyoming.svg.png'}];
}
```

When you search and select, its only taking one value as the entry itself is the one will be taken. However, what if I want to take, for example, beside the address, also a resident's name that reserved for future use or even in a form?

I tried to do that by passing a value like item.residentName, it will only display a list of address with undefined follow each of the address (pre-condition is that residentName is populated correctly). or if I pass the .push(object), that object is an object instead of a var with value only, it wil show each list item as [Object, object].

**==Further clarification**
For example in this last step of `getLocation()`, I will want to pass instead of just `item.formatted_address`, I want to also pass `item.geometry` while the list generated will still display formatted_address.

Please let me know if it makes sense.

Thank you

Comment: Just change the plunk to a right one

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to achieve. Could you be more specific? Can you provide an example of what you want to bind to the model and how you want it to be displayed by the typeahead?

Comment: @apairet I just added clarification. if that make sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/hCIjHfEYDXhiCL4lOMBb

The view was modified as follows:

```
typeahead="address as address.formatted_address for address in getLocation($viewValue)"
```

'address' will thus be bound to the model. It will be displayed as the 'formatted_address'

You can find more about all the possibilities in the doc:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select look at the ng-options syntax

The controller was modified as follows:

```
angular.forEach(res.data.results, function(item){
addresses.push({
    formatted_address: item.formatted_address,
    geometry: item.geometry
    });
});
```